# How to connect to SQL Server over the internet using IP to run windows application?

Tags: sql-server, windows, connection-string

I have 2 machines. Machine A has SQL Server installed and database will run on this machine. Machine B is far away and will connect to this database for operations.

Windows form application will be running on both machines.

I can't get connection from Machine B to Machine A for to access the SQL Server database.

I use connectionString="Data Source=IP,PORT;... " in my `app.config`.

IP I am using is my computer IP found by ipconfig command.

In SQL Server config manager, shared memory, named pipes, TCP/IP protocols are enabled.

- In TCP/IP properties > IP Address tab, IPALL has 1433 port configured.
- In TCP/IP properties > IP Address tab, IP4 is active and enabled and port is 1433. IP address is displaying there but shows different IP than my computer IP.

Tried turning off windows firewall as well as added 1433 as inbound port.

My `app.config` file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="MassComputers.Properties.Settings.MassCompConnectionString"
             connectionString="Data Source=xxx.xxx.80.80,1433;Initial Catalog=MassComp;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=pass@word1"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

I want to use / access db that is running on machine A from machine B over the internet. (machines are not in LAN)

I tried lot of different solutions from the community but none of them really work.

**EDIT: I was able to make a connection from machine B to machine A(SQL server is running) using public IP directly. 
But machine A's public IP will be changed when it connects to internet every time. How do I make it use static IP so that my connection string remain same?**

Comment: The bear is usually setting up a public static IP and port forwarding that to the private IP and port. You've done that right? You aren't pointing a private IP at a private IP across the internet? If you have, I would try packet capture.

Comment: both machines are at separate location and not having any internal network. this will be public IP address. I am trying to use machine A's public IP in connection string for machine B' app config.

Comment: Actually I got it to work. I did port forwarding for 1433 into my router configuration. btw, this video is very helpful just in case if anyone needs in future - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgWOZT6za3g